# Fetch data from the MongoDB database based on the value of the _class field in Spring data mongodb

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection called `bonds`, in which I store two object types of data:

```
@Document(collection = "bonds", collation = "en")
public class BoundsQuotes {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String isin;

    private Long ytmClose;
    private Long ytmVwap;
    private Long beyClose;
    private Long beyVwap;
    private Long vwap;
    private Long close;
    private Long closeChange;
    private Long volume;
    private Long value;

    private LocalDateTime lastTradeTime;
    // getter and setter
}

@Document(collection = "bonds", collation = "en")
public class Bonds {

    @Id
    private string id;
    private String isin;
    private String name;
    private String type1;
    private String type2;
    private String nameEn;
    private String symbol;
    private String symbolEn;
    private String currency;
    private String issuerClass;

    private Long parValue;
    private Long numOfPayments;
    private Long emissionVolume;

    private float couponRate;

    private LocalDate issueDate;
    private LocalDate maturityDay;
    private LocalDate accrualStartDate;
    // getter and setter
}

@Repository
public interface BondsRepository extends MongoRepository<Bonds, String>, ListQuerydslPredicateExecutor<Bonds> {
}

@Repository
public interface BoundsQuotesRepository extends MongoRepository<BoundsQuotes, String>, ListQuerydslPredicateExecutor<BoundsQuotes> {
}
```

Now my question is, how can I create queries based on the `_class` field?
Is this even possible?
Thank you for guiding me in this matter

I am new to this. I searched on Google but could not find a suitable article for this topic.